# Passing RFC3339 standard time to InfluxDB, resulting in wrong results

Tags: python, timestamp, influxdb, rfc3339

I am trying to populate data into [InfluxDB](https://influxdata.com/) using Python. My [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) timestamp is "2016-01-11T01:07:39+05:30".  When I try to pass this to InfluxDB, it returns a time of: "2016-01-10T19:37:39Z", while I actually want the time in InfluxDB to be "2016-01-11T01:07:39". I have even tried to pass only "2016-01-11T01:07:39" leaving "+5:30", but still it gives me no result. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB converts all timestamps to UTC for storage. `2016-01-11T01:07:39+05:30` is `2016-01-10T19:37:39Z` (the `Z` indicates UTC). I'm not sure why that seems incorrect to you.

To store `2016-01-11T01:07:39`, you must submit the full RFC3339 UTC timestamp `2016-01-11T01:07:39Z`, which includes the mandatory `Z`.